# Compute the posterior probability given a Bernoulli distributed likelihood

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, bayesian, coin-flipping

In a coin flip, we would like to compute p(theta|Data), where theta is the underlying parameter.

- The prior follows a beta distribution with parameters a and b.
- The likelihood follows a Bernoulli distribution which gives us the probability of coming up heads.

Here is the code implementation:

```
    a = 1  # a and b are the beta distribution's parameters
    b= 1
    num = 1e5 #Number of candidate theta values
    z= 17220 #Number of heads
    N= 143293 #Total number of flips

    Theta = seq(0.07,0.12, length.out= num)
    prior = dbeta(Theta, a,b) #Compute the prior at each value 

    likelihood = Theta^z *(1-Theta)^(N-z)

    pData = likelihood * prior /sum(likelihood * prior) #Compute evidence
    posterior = likelihood*prior / pData
```

I would like to verify that the posterior is equal to the analytical solutions beta(a+z, N-z+b). However, since the likelihood equals 0 because the theta values are small, the probability of the evidence is a Nan and so is the posterior.

I have tried computing the log likelihood but it gives me a large negative number which is equal to 0 when taking the exponential.

```
 Theta = seq(0.07,0.12, by= num_steps)
 lprior = log(dbeta(Theta, a,b)) #Compute the log prior at each value 

 llikelihood = log(Theta)*z + log(1-Theta)*(N-z) #log likelihood

 lpData = llikelihood + lprior - sum(llikelihood + lprior) #compute evidence

  lposterior = llikelihood+lprior - lpData
  posterior = exp(lposterior)
  plot(Theta, posterior, type="l")
  lines(Theta, exp(llikelihood), type="l")
  lines(Theta, exp(lprior), type="l")
```

If my ultimate goal is to have a nice graph that shows the posterior, likelihood and prior like so

[image: this]

**How should I be computing each value?**

Comment: You definitely want to work with log likelihoods. You might be able to check that `log_posterior = log(analytic_solution)`. If bringing the logs back onto the original scale is causing problems, you could just do everything on the log scale.

Comment: Your prior has the same value (1) for each point of theta. Is this intentional?

Comment: I am assuming an informative prior that is beta distributed, that is why dbeta will always give values equal to 1. Do you think I should compute it differently?

Comment: @JosephClarkMcIntyre I edited the post to include the log scale computation. I am still finding zeros in the end. I am sure there a mistake in my computation.

Comment: But you're exponentiating at the end with `posterior = exp(lposterior)`, and you said that's where the issues are coming in. So just work with `lposterior` and compare it to the log of the analytic solution.

Comment: @JosephClarkMcIntyre : 
dbeta(Theta, z+a, N-z+b) gives me a 1, hence the log gives me a 0. Do you think that using the beta prior /Bernoulli likelihood can't work for small theta values? If my ultimate goal is to plot the posterior, likelihood and prior. How should I be computing each of those values to avoid zeros everywhere?

Comment: Did you try `dbeta(Theta, z+a, N-z+b, log = TRUE)`? Sometimes there's not enough precision in the way the numbers are stored to first get the pdf and then log it, but R will return a log directly (I feel like you should be get `dbeta(Theta, z+a, N-z+b) = 0`, but 'dbeta(Theta, z+a, N-z+b, log = TRUE) = -(some large number)'; when I used Theta = .07, N = 143293, z = 17220, a = 1, b = 1, I got -2308)

Comment: You are right log=True solves the issue of the analytical formula but not the bernoulli formula : llikelihood = log(Theta)*z + log(1-Theta)*(N-z) #log likelihood.Zeros every where... 
. And how do I plot the likelihood, prior and posterior in a graph?

Comment: @JosephClarkMcIntyre maybe there is something wrong with my calculation of the prior or likelihood? Why can't I get a graph of the Bernoulli that resembles the normal distributions since I have a lot of samples?

Comment: Perhaps try `log1p(-Theta)` instead of `log(1-Theta)`, in case it's a numerical stability issue.

Comment: I don't get those at all. When I try the same theta, N, and z as I mentioned above, I get -54941.66. Given the values of theta you used, the log will always be negative, and you should never get a number near 0 (unless you exponentiate, which I think is a mistake).

Comment: My utlimate goal is to actually replicate the results of the library(bayesAB) for A/B testing. To compute the posterior of the treatment and control, I wanted to do the same thing as in the coin flipping scenario. Do you have any idea, how the posterior is computed in that package?  `library(bayesAB)
bayes.test <- bayesTest(control$converted,treatment$converted, priors = c('alpha' = 1, 'beta' = 1), n_samples = 1e5, distribution = 'bernoulli')
print(bayes.test)`

Comment: I think I got it. I'll be posting an answer soon. Thank you @JosephClarkMcIntyre 
 for your thorough clarifications and merv for your edits and numerical stability trick :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer has been provided through the comment section by @JosephClarkMcIntyre.

Here is a summary:

- In a Bernoulli trial, when N -the total number of trials- and z -the total number of success are large and the underlying parameter theta is small, it is better to only operate in the log space and never take the exponential.
- Moreover, since the log function is increasing, comparing the log posteriors of two distributions is similar to comparing the posterior.
- The above implementation was wrong because the formula for computing the evidence is not correct. p(evidence) = sum(likelihood*prior), p(log_evidence)= sum(log_likelihood +log_prior)

This is the final code, where the prior, likelihood and evidence are in the log space:

```
  a = 1  # a and b are the beta distribution's paramteres
  b= 1
  num_steps = 1e5
  z= 17220 #Number of heads
  N= 143293 #Total number of flips

  Theta = seq(from=0.07,to=0.12, length.out= num_steps)
  lprior = dbeta(Theta, a,b,log=TRUE) #Compute the log prior at each value 

  llikelihood = log(Theta)*z + log1p(-Theta)*(N-z) #log likelihood

  lpData = sum(llikelihood + lprior) #compute log of the evidence

  lposterior = llikelihood+lprior - lpData
  plot(Theta,log(dbeta(Theta,a+z,N-z+b)))
  plot(Theta, lposterior, type="l")
```

However, the analytical and the computed log posterior are not the same as shown in the graph..

Feel free to comment if you think there is a flaw in this answer or explain why the analytical and computed log posterior are not the same. ^^